# H.265 の利用にあたって、特許ライセンス問題を解決するにはどこと契約すればよいでしょうか？

Tags: ffmpeg, ライセンス

ffmpeg で h265エンコードを行いたいと考えています。
その際、特許のライセンスは各自で解決する必要があります。

具体的にどこと契約をする必要があるのでしょうか

Comment: ライセンスの話はあくまで「エンコード・デコードを行うコーデック周り」に関わる話なので、少なくともどのコーデックを使うつもりなのかを明確にする必要があると思いますし、法律も関わってくる話なので (特に企業としての利用を考えている場合) 法務部などへの相談もまずは検討してください。

Comment: 最近更新された(基本は古い)記事のようですが、参考になるかも。[H.265/HEVC特許暗黒時代](https://qiita.com/yohhoy/items/c2579097a507b1fbdddb)